# Using DNSMasq to route hostname traffic to local hostname address

Tags: dnsmasq

I have a particular setup where a Minishift VM is publishing some URLs accessible locally in a format such as:

http://some_app.192.168.64.2.xip.io/

This address is only accessible locally and is the only way to access some_app.

For some security concerns with the authentication server, I also need to route traffic from say:

**some_app.some.dev.domain** to my local **some_app.192.168.64.2.xip.io** address.

Notice the domain name change here, this essentially seems like an alias.

I was hoping to perform this using DNSMasq. Is routing from hostname to hostname possible with DNSMasq? If not, what technique should I use instead?

I am running this setup on Mac OS.

Many thanks,